# How to completely remove Chat Bot created by Chat API?

Tags: google-hangouts

I created test Chat Bot two month ago using Chat API and service account and used it.

Then I disabled the bot and remove Chat API from the project. But I still can find this bot in the Chat by the name. It has status Disabled but exists.

Is it possible completely remove it from G Suite domain available bots?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the Chat API should remove the bot from Hangouts Chat. Do you still see it after refreshing Chat or deleting your cache?